# Seekbar creating EditTexts and then getting entries for further use

Tags: android, arrays, seekbar

This code creates a seekbar and makes the seekbar create as many EditText fields as the slider is at / remove ones that would be too much. This code is in OnActivityCreated

```
final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) getActivity()
  .findViewById(R.id.npv_calcfields);
EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());
editText.setId(i);
editText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
  LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  SeekBar bar = (SeekBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.npv_seekbar);
  final TextView selection = (TextView) getActivity()
    .findViewById(R.id.npv_selected);
  bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekbar, int progress,
      boolean fromUser) {
      selection.setText("You have selected " + progress + " periods.");
      if (progress == 0) {
        String normalstring = getActivity().getResources()
          .getString(R.string.npv1);
        selection.setText(normalstring);
      }
      if (i > progress) {
        while (i > progress) {
          i--;
          EditText editText = (EditText) getActivity()
            .findViewById(i);
          linearLayout.removeView(editText);
        }
      } else {
        while (i < progress) {
          EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());
          editText.setId(i);
          editText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
          linearLayout.addView(editText);
          editText.setHint("Cash Flow " + i);
          i++;
        }
      }
    }
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
    }
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
    }
  });
```

This code is in the general class area:

```
int i = 0;
EditText r = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.npv_rate);
Button calc = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.npv_calc);
EditText[] DynamicField = new EditText[16];
```

Now I want users to input numbers into those edittext fields and then I want to do some math on them: `Entry / (Math.pow(1+r, i)` with `i` beeing the id of the field. The first entry should therefore be calculated as this: `entry/(1+r)^0`. This is what I tried but it doesn't work. It just crashes on startup.

```
calc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Double r1 = Double.parseDouble(r.getText().toString());
    EditText editText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(i);
    TextView answer = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.npv_answer);
    double[] CashFlows;
    CashFlows = new double[i];
    double result = 0;
    CashFlows[i] = (Double.parseDouble(editText.getText()
      .toString())) / (Math.pow(1 + r1, i));
    for (double d : CashFlows) {
      result += d;
    }
    answer.setText("answer is " + result);
  }
});
```

What did I do wrong? by the way only the last code segment isnt working. if i comment that out it all works fine i tested it :) just dosent do anything obviuosly :)

ok a little background on the errorlog that you can see here: http://pastebin.com/G8iX6Pkm
EDIT: the entire class file can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/dxA91dst, the entire project can be found here: https://github.com/killerpixler/Android-Financial-Calculator.git

the class file is a fragment that gets loaded in a DetailsActivity when somebody clicks on a listitem from the Main activity. Like i said the error has to be in the button listener because it was working before i added it.

Comment: *It just crashes on startup* isn't very helpful. Please add the stacktrace with the exception from the `logcat`.

Comment: You have a `NullPointerException` in your code. Put some logs to see which variable is `null`. I can't see your full code so I can't say something specific so test for `null` the following views: `calc`, `r`, `editText` and `answer`.

Comment: the logs will take a bit as im not home, i added an edit however with a link to the full class file and with a github link to the entire project. The file in question is F_NPV.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `NullPointerException` comes from the fact that you initialize your `Views` using the `getActivity()` method where you declare them as fields in the `F_NPV` class. The method `getActivity()` method will return a valid `Activity` reference after the callback `onAttach()` is called, so the way you initialize the views will not work as, at that moment(when the fields of the `Fragment` class are initialized) the method `getActivity` will return `null`, no valid reference. The correct way to do that initialization is doing it in the `onActivityCreated` callback:

```
EditText r;
Button calc;
//...
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    r = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.npv_rate);
    calc = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.npv_calc);
//...
```

Also, if I may, some suggestions regarding your code:

You're doing some double's parsing from Strings and it may be a good idea to check the input so you don't throw a `NumberFormatException`. For example, if the user creates some `EditTexts` and then clicks the calculate `Button`(I know, it sounds silly, but there are chances the user will do it(I did it for example)), you'll throw a `NumberFormatException` as you try to parse an empty `String`. Instead make a little check:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Double r1 = Double.parseDouble((r.getText().toString())
                    .equals("") ? "0" : r.getText().toString());
    EditText editText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(i);
    TextView answer = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.npv_answer);
    double[] CashFlows;
    CashFlows = new double[i];
    double result = 0;
    String tmp = editText.getText().toString();
    CashFlows[i] = (Double.parseDouble(tmp.equals("") ? "0" : tmp))
                        / (Math.pow(1 + r1, i));
    //...
```

Also, even if you have correct values in the `EditText` the above code will throw a `NullPointerException`, as the `editText` variable will be `null`. The reason for this is in the `while` loops that you used to create the fields. For example, if the user moves the `SeekBar` to 3 than the `while` loop will run 3 times, each time incrementing the `i` value. So `i` will be `0`, `1`, `2`, so far correct but because you increment `i` each time the final `i` will be `4`. Now in the `onClick` method you'll look for an `EditText` with the id `i`, but as there is no `EditText` in the layout with the id `4`, the view will be `null`.

Also, try to give your classes better names, you may know very well what they mean but you could be making things worse for someone that reads your code(like F_PNV, F_PV etc).

Code for the `onActivityCreated` method. This should solve what you're trying to do(if I understand what you want):

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    r = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.npv_rate);
    calc = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.npv_calc);
    final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) getActivity()
            .findViewById(R.id.npv_calcfields);
    SeekBar bar = (SeekBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.npv_seekbar);
    final TextView selection = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(
            R.id.npv_selected);
    bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekbar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            selection
                    .setText("You have selected " + progress + " periods.");
            if (progress == 0) {
                String normalstring = getActivity().getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.npv1);
                selection.setText(normalstring);
                linearLayout.removeAllViews(); // the progress is 0 so
                                                // remove all the views that
                                                // are currently present
            } else {                
                int currentChilds = linearLayout.getChildCount();
                if (currentChilds < progress) {
                    while (currentChilds != progress) {
                        EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());                        
                        editText.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        linearLayout.addView(editText);
                        currentChilds++;                            
                    }
                } else if (currentChilds > progress) {
                    while (currentChilds != progress) {
                        linearLayout.removeViewAt(linearLayout
                                .getChildCount() - 1);
                        currentChilds--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        }
    });

    calc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Double r1 = Double.parseDouble((r.getText().toString())
                    .equals("") ? "0" : r.getText().toString());
            TextView answer = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(
                    R.id.npv_answer);
            final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) getActivity()
                    .findViewById(R.id.npv_calcfields);
            int size = linearLayout.getChildCount();
            double[] CashFlows = new double[size];
            double result = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                EditText editText = (EditText) linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
                String tmp = editText.getText().toString();
                CashFlows[i] = (Double.parseDouble(tmp.equals("") ? "0"
                        : tmp)) / (Math.pow(1 + r1, i));
            }
            for (double d : CashFlows) {
                result += d;
            }
            answer.setText("answer is " + result);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: thanks for the info, as for the while loop, my heart isnt attached to it but when i dont have it, there is a lag and most times when you slide down from 4 to 2 it will still have 3 fields left, the while loop fixed that. Also why will the final i be 4? i starts at 0 so incrementing it 3 times makes it 1,2,3 ? what if i initilaize it as -1? would that work? (not a int anymore then but w/e).

Comment: Also for the class names :) F_ denotes a fragment :) and the other things after are names of a financial mathematics term NPV is for example the short form for Net Present Value, PV = Present Value, = PVAnn = Present Value of Annuity

Comment: @Killerpixler You could put a log entry and see what is the value for `i` when you enter the `onClick` method ;). Generally, abbreviations like the ones you used are not very descriptive and you should avoid them. Anyway, I've edited my answer and added some code on how I would write the `onActivityCreated` method.

Comment: Awesome, it is working perfectly now. Thank you sooooo much. it can handle empty ones perfectly. Thank you so much. It is also good to know that my idea with the array was not completely wrong, just that the code needed to be changed a little. Thanks again.